# Как получить ответ от бд и записать её правильно в переменную

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется ответ от бд: [{"balance":100000000}]

И так же имеется переменная $amount = 100

Как получить из ответа от бд [{"balance":100000000}], получить: 100000000, чтобы в последующем вычесть из "balance", $amount

К примеру запрос выглядит так $balance = DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $user_id)->get('balance'); Но ответ прилетает в таком виде: [{"balance":100000000}] , а нужно 100000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял то так

```
DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $user_id)->first()->balance
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped